# Java Static Lookup Constants - Need Design idea

Tags: java, static, constants

I'm new to Java and need some help in design for holding static lookup values.

I have various (150) statuses like TRANSACTIONSTATUS, LOGINSTATUS, BOOKINGSTATUS etc, each has it's own set of key and value.

Eg:

1. TRANSACTIONSTATUS(PD="PENDING", PE="PENDING EXCEPTION", PS="PENDING SUBMISSION")
2. LOGINSTATUS(LG="LOGGED IN", FD="FAILED" UL="USER LOCKED")

I'm trying to come up how to hold these static values in memory when the application starts up and refer wheneever i need it. I have read through java enums and keeping properties in hash maps, but not exactly sure how. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I could think of. You can similarly construct an enum for LoginStatus. Any decent Java reference should help your further.

```
public enum TransactionStatus
{
    PD("Pending"),
    PE("Pending Exception"),
    PS("Pending Submission");

    private final String value;

    TransactionStatus(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree. Is there a way to manage all the status in single enum? Like TransactionStatus, LoginStatus etc?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a single Enum.   Using separate enums would prevent code from applying a TransactionStatus during a Login event.

Comment: Just to re-iterate, the categories of enum's that you have provided are applicable to different objects. Creating a separate enum for every category is the right way to go. This ensures that you are setting the right status for the right object by using a type-safe status setter. Having a single enum could easily result in you setting for e.g. BookingStatus.FAILED on a Transaction. And as far as accessing them goes, you can access any enum without having any special construction. For e.g. TransactionStatus.PD is available to you anytime.